# Which one is better to check if the key is in the hash_map in C++? at with try...catch block or find with iterator comparison?

Tags: c++, hashmap

As far as I know there are two basics ways to check if an item is in the hash_map:

Let's say we have a hash_map: `hash_map<string, int> amap`

If we are gonna check whether "abc" is in the map then we can do

```
hash_map<string, int>::iterator itr = amap.find("abc");
if (itr != amap.end()) //in the map
```

or:

```
try {
    int value = amap.at("abc");
}
catch(out_of_range& e) {
    //not there    
}
```

Just wanna know which one is better? for efficiency concern?

Comment: Exceptions are expensive in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find()`. Testing the iterator is almost certainly going to be much cheaper than catching an exception.

Comment: +1 Not to mention on VisualStudio debugging sessions spamming the bejeezors of First Chance Exception notifications in your Output window.